# [Debian][ProFTPD]: Permission denied when I try to edit file

Tags: debian, proftpd

I've got a problem with ProFTPD on Debian. I use users from MySQL database and I can login with it, but can't edit files. When I try to edit file, TotamCommander throws 550: Permission Denied. This is my proftpd.conf file:

```
## Load modules
Include /etc/proftpd/modules.conf

## Base FTP settings
UseIPv6             on
ServerName          "server name"
ServerType          standalone
MultilineRFC2228        on 
DefaultServer           on 

# Port 21 is the standard FTP port.
Port                21

# Umask 022 is a good standard umask to prevent new dirs and files
# from being group and world writable.
Umask               022

### Allow files override
AllowOverwrite                  on

### Allow retrive download
AllowRetrieveRestart            on

### Allow restore upload 
AllowStoreRestart               on

### Allow .ftpaccess files 
AllowOverride                   on

# To prevent DoS attacks, set the maximum number of child processes
# to 30.  If you need to allow more than 30 concurrent connections
# at once, simply increase this value.  Note that this ONLY works
# in standalone mode, in inetd mode you should use an inetd server
# that allows you to limit maximum number of processes per service
# (such as xinetd).
MaxInstances            30

# Set the user and group under which the server will run.
User                proftpd
Group               proftpd

# To cause every FTP user to be "jailed" (chrooted) into their home
# directory, uncomment this line.
DefaultRoot ~

# Allow login for root
RootLogin           off

# Normally, we want files to be overwriteable.
<Directory /*>
    AllowOverwrite          off
    HideNoAccess            on
    <Limit READ>
     AllowAll
    </Limit>
    <Limit Write>
     DenyAll
    </Limit>
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/*>
        AllowOverwrite   on
    <Limit STOR CMD MKD WRITE>
     AllowALL
    </Limit>
    <Limit RETR DELE>
     DenyALL
    </Limit>
</Directory>

# A basic anonymous configuration, no upload directories.  If you do not
# want anonymous users, simply delete this entire <Anonymous> section.
<Anonymous ~ftp>
  User              ftp
  Group             ftp

  # We want clients to be able to login with "anonymous" as well as "ftp"
  UserAlias         anonymous ftp

  # Limit the maximum number of anonymous logins
  MaxClients            10

  # We want 'welcome.msg' displayed at login, and '.message' displayed
  # in each newly chdired directory.
  DisplayLogin          welcome.msg

  # Limit WRITE everywhere in the anonymous chroot
  <Limit WRITE>
    DenyAll
  </Limit>
</Anonymous>

#
# Users needs a valid shell
#
RequireValidShell               off

## Configure SQL
Include /etc/proftpd/sql.conf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to chmod your file:

```
chmod +w <file>
```

Comment: I've already done it, it does not help :/